# Grep for contents between two markers with newlines

Tags: search, grep, sed

Just curious if there's a way I can show the output between two markers?

I was trying `grep -r "<cron_expr>.*</run>" *` but it doesn't seem to be returning as
expected. Which is to say its not showing newline breaks?

So I guess the the real question is how can i find out what between two markers
regardless of newline BS. I can't install on this system so no pcregrep =(

Maybe AWK?

(P.s. someone should make an AWK tag)

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <enterprise_reward_balance_warning_notification>
            <schedule><cron_expr>1 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>enterprise_reward/observer::scheduledBalanceExpireNotification</model></run>
        </enterprise_reward_balance_warning_notification>
        <enterprise_reward_expire_points>
            <schedule><cron_expr>1 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>enterprise_reward/observer::scheduledPointsExpiration</model></run>
        </enterprise_reward_expire_points>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

I just want to show whats on the `<schedule>` and `<run>` line(s if more than one, like above) anytime I see  and what file they're in.

Comment: `grep` and `sed` are both line-oriented.  `awk` can use an arbitrary delimiter in place of newline, but still needs some kind of delimiter.  What exactly are you looking for?  You may be going about it the wrong way (for example, none of these tools is really appropriate for HTML/XML, and not ideal for JSON).

Comment: Yeah i'm searching through a bunch of config.xml's on our server to try and figure out when and what they're running in their private crontab, i'll post an example in a minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AWK script**

AWK is probably the answer using the /start/,/stop/ pattern like this:

```
/<schedule>/,/<\/schedule>/ {
    print;
}
/<run>/,/<\/run>/ {
    print;
}
```

This will print everything in the schedule and run tags (including the tags) and will preserve new lines. Adapt it to print what you need. To run it:

```
cat myfile.txt | awk -f script.awk
```

**XSLT style sheet**

Here's an XSLT version that should do something very similar. Run it using xsltproc, which should be installed by default.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="schedule">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="run">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I can't install new things on our webserver so I need to work with the tools I have (grep sed/awk) =( Could I spit out all content between two instances of crontab?

Comment: How do you do the awk one without including the search tags?

Comment: AWK may not be the right tool if you want to exclude the search tags because it is line oriented so basically it matches a start line and an end line. If you want to exclude the delimiters, the XSLT version will be more adapted because XSLT understands the XML structure and will let you manipulate child nodes. In practice the XSLT example above strips out all XML tags and outputs the text only.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do what I think you want too do.

you could use sed

say I wanted to get the numbers in between lspci -nn

it spits out numbers like this

[1234:4321]

I would do this

```
lspci -nn| sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/'
```

This is my first post here so I hope the escape character's are correct. But I am not sure what you are trying to do.